# is a^(m)b^(n) | m >= 99 and n>=999 a regular language?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, pumping-lemma

I've been stuck on this problem for a while. Say we have the following language?

```
a^(m)b^(n) | m >= 99 and n>=999
```

I'm trying to use the pumping lemma to prove that it isn't regular because intuitively to me it seems like it isn't. Can anyone please give me a concrete answer?

Comment: Take the language of 99 a's, followed by a*, followed by 999 b's, followed by b*. It doesn't really come much simpler than that.

Answer (score 1):

The language is regular here is a regular expression that fits for the language:

$$a^*(\underbrace{aa\dots}_{\text{99 times}})b^*(\underbrace{bbb\dots}_{\text{999 times}})$$

Answer (score 0):

A grammar would be $S\to a^{99}Ab^{999}B$, $A\to a$, $A\to aA$, $B\to b$, $B\to bB$.

This proves it is regular.

(Probably a more specific answer could be given if you could tell what programming language you are using (because your question has a strong smell of regular expression in context of programming languages).)

Answer (score -1):

The language is the language accepted by the regular expression `/aa`...`aa*bb`...`bb*/` where the number of `a` and `b` hiding in the dots is adjusted to needs.